# Check if time is greater than specific time in a day

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Probably asked before but can't find answer for this. **How do I check if time is greater than 17:30 every day?**

My case is that I would need to check if current time is greater than 17:30 on Monday to Friday and if today is Saturday I have to check if time is greater than 15:30.

I do prefer use of Moment.js.

Comment: "I do prefer use of Moment.js." ?

Comment: Why did you change the accepted answer?

Comment: I went through these answers and I indeed mention Moment.js as a preferred way to solve this. So that is more accurate answer for this question. There is nothing wrong with your answer but I think using moment.js the final function is cleaner way to solve this (atleast it is easier to read).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here an example with `moment.js`

```js
function check() {
  var now = moment();
  var hourToCheck = (now.day() !== 0)?17:15;
  var dateToCheck = now.hour(hourToCheck).minute(30);
  
  return moment().isAfter(dateToCheck);
}

console.log(check())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, and your approach is reasonable, but I think you missed a few things.

Answer (score 5):

You can just check for the time using `Date()`. Seriously, you don't need a big plugin for this:

```js
var curTime = new Date();
var day = curTime.getDay();
curTime = parseInt(curTime.getHours() + "" + ("0" + curTime.getMinutes()).substr(-2) + "" + ("0" + curTime.getSeconds()).substr(-2));

if ((curTime > 173000 && day > 0 && day < 6) || (curTime > 153000 && day <= 0 && day >= 6))
  console.log("It's a good time!");
else
  console.log("It's not a good time!");
```

*Let me know if there's a case, this fails!*

Comment: You forgot to zero-pad

Comment: @MattJohnson You got me! `:)` Updated.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer to use unit multipliers and keep everything numeric, but then of course your comparison values would be in terms of total seconds.  Another approach would be just to compare elements separately, the way you do with day.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give another approach using moment.js:

```
var now = moment();
var day = now.day();
var today1730 = moment('17:30','HH:mm');
var today1530 = moment('15:30','HH:mm');
var ok = day > 0 && day < 7 ? now.isSameOrAfter(today1730) : now.isSameOrAfter(today1530);

if (ok) { ... }
```

Comment: i used this one and it helped but what i did was as follows : time1 = moment(outTime,'HH:mm');
 const time2 = moment(inTime,'HH:mm');
 return time1.isSameOrAfter(time2);